# Cloudera impala with spring framework?

Tags: spring, impala

Can you use cloudera impala with spring web or spring boot just to even make a simple request and return some content when hitting a url? If so, how? There does not seem to be any documentation on how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Impala offers a JDBC interface, it can be accessed by a Spring application. You can easily build a web application using Spring MVC as its IHM (or spring-data-rest if you prefere a simple REST API), and accessing a Cloudera Impala system through a DAO layer using spring Jbdc.

The layered architecture of Spring allows for that.